# Placing Transparent Image to Another non-transparent image

Tags: php, image, gif

How can I place a transparent image to a background image using PHP?

I have here my code:

```
$width = 400;
$height = 400;

$base_image = imagecreatefrompng("img/frame1.png");
$top_image = imagecreatefrompng("randyorton.png");
$merged_image = "merged.png";

imagealphablending($base_image, true);
imagesavealpha($base_image, true);
imagealphablending($top_image, true);
imagesavealpha($top_image, true);


imagecopy($base_image, $top_image, 10080, 10080, 0, 0, $width, $height);
imagecopy($base_image, $top_image, 80, 80, 0, 0, $width, $height);
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($base_image, $merged_image);
```

What's wrong with this? The image I am creating now has a black background on it.

Please see this picture for reference:

[image]

Am I making sense?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I get it. I have a big width and height for the top image. I just get the size of the top image and pass it on the imagecopy function. :D